# MissingOutputException and latency-wait error with snakemake

Tags: snakemake, blast

I am trying to makeblastdb database in snakemake:

```
workdir: "/path/to/workdir/"

(SAMPLES,) =glob_wildcards('/path/to/workdir/{sample}.fasta')

rule all:
    input: 
        expand("{sample}.fasta.{ext}", sample=SAMPLES, ext=["nhr", "nin", "nsq"])

rule makeblastdb:
    input:
        reference = "/path/to/workdir/{sample}.fasta"
    output:
        out = "{sample}.fasta.{ext}"
    shell:
        /Tools/ncbi-blast-2.9.0+/bin/makeblastdb -in {input.reference} -out {output.out} -dbtype nucl"
```

I get this error:

```
MissingOutputException in line 11:
Missing files after 10 seconds:
This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with --latency-wait.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: This just means that the code was executed, but the output specified under output is not actually there. What happens if you execute the command yourself on the command line?

Comment: but the files are there....

Comment: Oh I see....when I execute the command i have fasta.00.nhr etc etc, how can I know in advance how many numbers will I have? My references are quite big 10-15 GB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would touch a file when `makeblastdb` completes and use that file as dummy input for the rules that need the blast database. This way you let blast deal with suffixes and accessory files. E.g.

```
rule makeblastdb:
    input:
        reference = "/path/to/workdir/{sample}.fasta",
    output:
        done = touch("{sample}.makeblastdb.done"),
    shell:
        r"""
        /Tools/ncbi-blast-2.9.0+/bin/makeblastdb -in {input.reference} -out {wildcards.sample} -dbtype nucl"
        """

rule blast:
    input:
        db_done= "{sample}.makeblastdb.done",
        ...
    output:
        ...
    shell:
        r"""
        blast -db {wildcards.sample} ...
        """
```

Comment: @user3224522 this is a better option than what I proposed, flagging a file is the cleanest solution here.

Comment: @user3224522 rule `all` can be anything you want of course. If you want the blast databases in `all` use `expand("{sample}.makeblastdb.done", sample= SAMPLES)`

Comment: seems it is working :) thank you very much guys for your help and suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

As you point out in the comments, you do not know how many files you get as output. There are two options:

- Make use of output [directories](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#directories-as-outputs).
- Make use of [checkpoints](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution), however this is kinda tricky to properly understand (in my opinion).

Untested but might just work:

rule makeblastdb:
    input:
        reference = "/path/to/workdir/{sample}.fasta"
    output:
        out = "{sample}.fasta.{ext}"
    shell:
        /Tools/ncbi-blast-2.9.0+/bin/makeblastdb -in {input.reference} -out {output.out} -dbtype nucl"

Here we mark the output as an output directory named sample-ext, and the output of ncbi-blast will be in this directory called sample.ext.

---

**edit**:

If we do not want all these output directories what we could do is say that we expect at least 1 output, and if that one exists we assume everything went fine:

```
rule makeblastdb:
    input:
        reference = "/path/to/workdir/{sample}.fasta"
    output:
        out = "{sample}.fasta.00.{ext}
    shell:
        /Tools/ncbi-blast-2.9.0+/bin/makeblastdb -in {input.reference} -out {wildcards.sample}.fasta.{wildcards.ext} -dbtype nucl"
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion...will this create many directories? Sorry in advance if I get this wrong...

Comment: Yes, this will create a directory for every sample and ext combination, which might be a lot.

Comment: yes I might have around 400 directories :D, and also when I blast I guess I need all .ext in one single directory... :/

Comment: is it strictly necessary to put  output files? because makeblastdb creates output files itself....

Comment: Yes, if you do not have an output then Snakemake does not know how to generate files :(.

Comment: @user3224522 take a look at the edit, would this work?

Comment: it is giving me this outputs: .fasta.nin.00.nhr

Comment: I don't think this solution works because depending on the size of the input file, makeblastdb will create output files with different names. On a small file, it will only create `{sample}.nhr`, `{sample}.nin`, etc. But when the file becomes large, then it starts creating these files `{sample}.00.nhr`, etc. If you want your pipeline to work on files of different sizes, then the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59289873/10229920) of @dariober will work